# doubleclick Not working with selectpicker boostrap class dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<select class= "selectpicker" id="cus_id">
<option value="654" >test1<option>
<option value="6877" >test2<option>
<option value="8687" >test3<option>
</select>


$('#cus_id ').dblclick(function() {
                        
var cus_id =this.value;
                                   
window.open("<?php echo base_url();?>tester/"+cus_id );
                            
   });
```

Here i will take the selected value cus_id  to do next operation on another tab . Without selectpicker class, dblclick function works well but Here the problem comes when i put selectpicker class dblclick event won't work
So sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `selectpicker` class to the `select` element would not affect your double click functionality. There seems to be some other error, more likely syntax error.

I can see the `html` added have multiple syntax issues like missing closing `option` tag, the selector has space in it `$('#cus_id ')`.

```js
$('#cus_id').dblclick(function() {
  console.log('Calling');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selectpicker" id="cus_id">
  <option value="654">test1</option>
  <option value="6877">test1</option>
  <option value="8687">test1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: No iam using selectpicker class for create dynamic search field in  selectbox when i click . Example [link] (https://select2.org/appearance)

Comment: (https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/)